# How can I customize the "Required background modes" Alert Box?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

In my App's plist file, there is a `Required background modes` key included that I need for `CoreBluetooth`.

Now when I start the App with Bluetooth turned off, a message box appears telling me to turn on Bluetooth. So this works fine. My question is how can I customize the appearance of the alert bbx? Or is it just possible to access this alert view in code?

This would be very helpful to know because this dialog lets me automatically switch to the bluetooth settings section, in iOS 11 it's no longer possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** to customize the look of a background mode alert.

What you can do is display a separate custom alert before/after the background mode alert's appearance.

This approach is used by many popular apps, for example, this is an alert displayed in Messenger before asking for the user's permission for accessing contacts:

[image: Custom alert in Messenger]